# CSS displays differently in two separate page

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
#main2 {
    width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#header2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
}
#contents2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #0F446D;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 365px;
    background: url('theImages/certBG.png') no-repeat bottom;
}
#store {
    background-image: url('theImages/certHeader.png');
    width: 231px;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

But this page: [Non Working Page](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/ccopy.php?zh=loadPage)
[image: Not Working]

shows the header "Your Information" differently than this page: [Working Page](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/test/label.htm)
[image: Working]

Can anyone please let me know why? and how to make the first page show the header correctly.

Comment: The contents of #store appear identical in both pages. FF/Win7.

Comment: yes they are identical and should work the same, right?

Comment: when I look into chrome debugger, you have two different background images. background-image: url('navigation.png'); (working page) and background-image: url('theImages/certHeader.png'); (non-working page)

Comment: it's two different folders but the exact same image. I had to change the name because that folder already had a image name navigation.png but they are the same image.

Comment: Both of them looks identical to me.Can you be little specific- why do you think both of them appears to be different?

Comment: I updated my question with screenshots so you can are clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `#store22{ display:block;}`

OR

> Add display:block; on line 22

and it works excellent as your demands. :)

Comment: All elements are default position static and display:inline. And the elements which we wanna apply padding and/or margin will not apply if we do not use display:block. If we use display:block, the elements covers its specific region.Here in this case you are giving margin and padding which is of no use without display:block.

Answer (score 2):

You require a **different CSS style-sheet** for internet explorer(**IE**):

Refer line 8,9 and 10 of following [page source](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/ccopy.php?zh=loadPage)(by clicking **ViewSource** in IE) .

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="theScriptsStyles/mainStyle-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Page [Link-1](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/ccopy.php?zh=loadPage) includes `IE Style-Sheet` while Page [Link-2](http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/test/label.htm) do not.

Both page looks identical in other browsers(Chrome, Firefox).Looks different in Internet Explore because of `mainStyle-ie.css`

[IE always has CSS issue](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml). Therefore,you have to target specifically your style-sheet for IE only. You will need to put condition code(like above) on heading section of the page.

Comment: I wonder what is it in the mainStyle or mainStyle-ie has that is causing it not to work :(

Comment: Even the same CSS code works different in different browser.This is called "the Cross-browser issue".http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553085/css-cross-browser-issue. Then everything works perfectly.I am freaking sure, that's the only reason. Rest of the thing is perfect.
Just embed the following CSS http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/theScriptsStyles/mainStyle-ie.css for IE.

Comment: used display:block for #store and it was working fine. Thanks